Am I allowed to steal a opponent's build before claiming my own in Cassino?
In the card game Cassino, there are many printed rules about building.  But I've never seen this one and it led to a heated discussion!
Let's say it's my turn, and I begin building in a legal way.   On my opponent's turn, he also starts a build.  On my next turn, am I allowed to steal his build before I complete my own?  The rules I have found only state that I must hold the card to claim my own build.  I can't find any rule that specifies when I am required to bring my original build home.
So... is it illegal to capture an opponent's build before claiming my own, and if so where is it stated?
